# SOLR & Hybris: Different Cores, Multiple Indexer Type with the same Composed Type

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

Is it possible to create two different indexedType with the same composed Type? Will it appear as two different cores in localhost:8983?

I successfully created an indexedType in Hybris 6.3 named myMediaVideoType with a composed type equal to Media. There is an existing indexedType named myMediaType having the same composed type (Media).

The problem is, I want it to appear in localhost:8983 (in core section), but it doesn't appear there.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a new indexedType with the same composed Type ? If you want to index new Data I would suggest adding new "SolrIndexedProperty"s for the already existing indexed Type

Comment: It's because I have different IndexerQuery for the two indexed type.

Comment: Can't those two queries be merged into one query that retrieves all the data(All the Media instances required) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good if you tell the exact scenario, one can suggest a better solution. Anyway, let me answer your questions.

> Is it possible to create two different indexedType with the same
>   composed Type?

Yes, you can create as many indexedType you want with the same Composed Type.

> Will it appears as two different cores in
>    localhost:8983?

Yes, if you configure different `SolrFacetSearchConfig` for each `IndexedType` with different `indexNamePrefix` value

**A snippet of Impex:**

```
# Declare the indexed type
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedType;identifier[unique=true];type(code);
;myMediaType;Media;
;myMediaVideoType;Media;

# Declare the FacetSearchConfig
INSERT_UPDATE SolrFacetSearchConfig;name[unique=true];description;indexNamePrefix;
;myMediaTypeFSC;facetSearchConfigDescription1;myMediaType;
;myMediaVideoTypeFSC;facetSearchConfigDescription2;myMediaVideoType;
```